# Get field Label in LWC for custom Object in Lightning Out for Managed Package

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package, lightning-out

I have a component where I need to get field Label.

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import CUSTOM_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/CUSTOM_OBJECT__c';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';

export default class Poc extends LightningElement {

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: CUSTOM_OBJECT })
    oppInfo({ data, error }) {
        if (data) console.log('Name => ', data.fields.Name.label);
    }

}
```

Above code works well if I just embed the component directly in lightning. But If above component is embeded inside a vf page I am getting this error

> You don't have access to this record. Ask your administrator for help
> or to request access.

Permission is there. I can see records and object in salesforce. Also I am testing with admin User.

I tried adding package prefix to the object name like

```
import CUSTOM_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/pk__CUSTOM_OBJECT__c';
```

But I got deployment error

> Invalid module id "pk__CUSTOM_OBJECT__c" for type "schema". Explicit
> use of namespace "pk" in file "fileName.js" is
> prohibited. Use default namespace "c" instead.

According to documentation of @Salesforce/schema I think they are recommending to add package name(Not explicitly mentioned but in example)

[image]
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_salesforce_modules

But adding namespace is not deployable.

If I use standard object like Account

```
import CUSTOM_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';
```

It works for both lightning out and embedding directly in lightning.

Is there any limitation of getting object info of custom objects in Lightning out for managed package.